# How do i pass a string variable to a javascript function and use it to get element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function that I want to re-use. I have 2 HTML onclick functions calling the same code. The first (instance 1) sends "this" and the second (instance 2) sends the id value. Instance 1 is a close button on the modal in itself, and instance 2 is a test cancel button within the modal body.

Instance 1 is working in the function when assigning the href value, however instance 2  is not, i.e. instance 1 closes the modal and instance 2 does not.

Can anyone please advise me where I am going wrong? Code example below.

```
<!-- HTML instance 1 -->
<a id="ModalClose" title="Close" onclick="CloseModal(this)" 
class="close">X</a>

<!-- HTML instance 2 -->
<button type="button" id="test123" 
onclick="CloseModal('ModalClose')">Close</button>

function CloseModal(ModalObj) {

    if (typeof ModalObj === 'object') {
        var x = document.getElementById(ModalObj.id);
    } else { 
        var x = document.getElementById(ModalObj); 
    }
    x.href = "#close";
}
```

Comment: Your code [seems to work as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/qp0w9v28/). What is the actual problem here?

Comment: @Teemu, instance 1 closes the modal and instance 2 does not.

Comment: There's no code for closing a modal in your example. Both, the link and the button changes the href of the link. Please add the related code to the question, and explain in details what goes wrong. "_not working_" is not a problem describtion.

Comment: my understanding is by applying the href element, it forces the modal to close, by diverting to another html element that does not exist. "Close" is just a coined term and not relative. if the type of is an object the href is assigned and the modal disappears, if the else statement is initiated, the href code completes but the modal does not disappear. I hope that provides some clarity. thanks.

Comment: How is that? Setting `href="#text"` just navigates to an element having id `text`, unless you don't have a specific click handler for the link. When you set the href via the button, the link is never clicked.

Comment: that is correct, there is no element with the ID of close causing the modal to close. mt query is that one way of initiation is working and another is not with no clear indication as to why when passing in a div id rather than the "this" control?

Comment: So, clicking the link "closes the modal". Again: __When you set the href via the button, the link is never clicked.__ Add `x.click();` after changing the href.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Thank you.

Comment: @Teemu, I cannot mark this as an answer within the comments, would you mind posting as an answer and i can mark it complete and credit you properly? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is effectively doing the same thing no matter if the link or the button was clicked, i.e. it adds a href to the link. The difference in behavior comes from the default action of those elements. Button has no specific default action (outside of forms), but link navigates to the location given in its href attribute.

Now when you click the button, nothing changes the location. To fix this, you've to manually click the link after changing its href. Add `x.click();` as the last line in the click handler function to click the link and get the default behavior.